# File Path not changing in code

Tags: java, filepath, eclipse-oxygen

So I have created a class that searches an excel file and prints all the rows and columns of the file. Now I have an exception file not found error. In order to fix this error I have changed the file path in the code but for some reason I get the same error and the error message in the console shows the previous file path I was using that gave me error.

I know the new file path is correct but Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize that the code has been updated. Here is the code from the class:

```
public class ExcelReader {
    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "K:\\Documents\\Project\\Netword_GUI\\Netword_GUI\\src\\libs\\cc2017.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

        /*
           =============================================================
           Iterating over all the sheets in the workbook (Multiple ways)
           =============================================================
         */

        // You can obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
        Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
        System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
            //System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0));
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }
        // Getting the Sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        // You can obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        if (sheet.getActiveCell() == null) {
            // Closing the workbook
            workbook.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Now here is the error message displayed in the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Placement\Private_Backup\Netword_GUI\Netword_GUI\src\cc2017.xlsx
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:205)
>     at ExcelReader.main(ExcelReader.java:13)

Notice: The file path in the console is different to the file path in the code. Previously the file path in the error message was in the code this is because I have the same class on another computer so the file path was changed as the location is different on the computer I am currently working on.

Comment: Try to clean and re-build your project (from the "Project" menu) .

Comment: Thank you I have tried this but now I am getting this error. Error: Could not find or load main class ExcelReader

Comment: @Berger- Please put this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the build in Eclipse is not up to date.

In that case you should clean and re-build your project (from the "*Project*" menu)

Answer (score 0):

could you please add your code to make every one get the big picture of your code to give you a correct answer 
  try this one

```
   File f=new File(fixed_file_path);  
   Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
```

Comment: when you are creating the file don't create it inside the workbook   i wrote a similar code to this for working with excel files                                                 check my answer i updated it